# Cannot view file even after ACL added

Tags: permissions, acl

This is similar to another question, but it does not seem like it explains the behavior I'm seeing. Below I am adding a specific user to get rx permissions on the Apache log access logs. However, even after adding the ACL, the ec2-user cannot cat the file.

```
[root]# setfacl -m u:ec2-user:rx /var/log/httpd/access_log-20170419
[root]# getfacl /var/log/httpd/access_log-20170419 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/log/httpd/access_log-20170419
# owner: root
# group: root user::rw- user:ec2-user:r-x group::r-- mask::r-x other::r--
[root]# exit 
exit 
$ whoami 
ec2-user 
$ more /var/log/httpd/access_log-20170419         
/var/log/httpd/access_log-20170419: Permission denied
```

It looks like the ACL should take precedence.

Comment: What do you get if ec2-user types `ls -l /var/log/httpd/`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of `/var/log/httpd`.  The permissions are probably only `rwx------`.  You need to give `ec2-user` access to this directory using `setfacl`